# Change region in google sql cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My current region for the Google SQL cloud is now in the USA.
I want to change the region to Europe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once created, a Cloud SQL instance cannot be moved between regions. You can create a new instance, export the old one and import it into the new one.

Comment: Do you now of a good resource that help to walk through the process of export / import for postgresql?

Answer (score 11):

Now you can move Cloud SQL with replica feature.

1. Create a replica in a destination region
2. Promote the `replica` into `primary` one
3. Change application database configuration

[image]

Comment: this is the solution. using replica then promote